# 'Invalid left-hand side in assignment' after webpack and babel build

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, node-modules, ecmascript-5

## Brief overview

I am struggling with porting a react app to be es5 compatible. We have special requirements to run the app on Chrome v37. Therefore i added es5 compatible polyfills, shimming and transpiling to the toolchain

### Tools and basic configuration

- Webpack (v5+), babel (v7+), npm, and typescript (v4.7+)
- core-js (v3.23+) for polyfills
- bundle file for our sources
- bundle file for vendor sources
- node_modules which are not es5 compatible are NOT excluded from babel-loader
- node_modules which are es5 compatible are excluded from babel-loader

I also tried:

- use different module types in the typescript.config (CommonJS, AMD and ES6)
- use different properties for strict mode in tthe typescript.config
- downgrade rtf.js package (but don't go under 3.0 because the author removed jquery with 3.0)

## Problem

Modern browsers do not throw any error. Old browser does.

The error states: 'Invalid left-hand side in assignment' in the vendor.bundle.js file on 'push.../node_modules/rtf.js/dist/RTFJS.bundle.js'

Chrome v37 throws following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment 
vendors.c543a78e.js:10131push.../node_modules/rtf.js/dist/RTFJS.bundle.js 
vendors.c543a78e.js:10131__webpack_require__ app.c543a78e.js:1802fn 
app.c543a78e.js:2048(anonymous function) index.js:7push.../node_modules/rtf.js/index.js 
vendors.c543a78e.js:10152__webpack_require__ app.c543a78e.js:1802fn 
app.c543a78e.js:2048(anonymous function) 
RtfTextConverter.ts?111d:4__webpack_modules__../controllers/sceneInterpreters
/compositeSceneInterpreter/RtfTextConverter.ts app.c543a78e.js:1533__webpack_require__ 
app.c543a78e.js:1802fn app.c543a78e.js:2048(anonymous function) 
CompositeSceneInterpreter.ts?8981:16__webpack_modules__../controllers/sceneInterpreters
/compositeSceneInterpreter/CompositeSceneInterpreter.ts 
app.c543a78e.js:1523__webpack_require__ app.c543a78e.js:1802fn 
app.c543a78e.js:2048(anonymous function) 
PlaylistInterpreter.ts?e5ab:6__webpack_modules__../PlaylistInterpreter.ts 
app.c543a78e.js:543__webpack_require__ app.c543a78e.js:1802fn 
app.c543a78e.js:2048(anonymous function) 
PlaylistManager.tsx?4d1a:5__webpack_modules__../PlaylistManager.tsx 
app.c543a78e.js:553__webpack_require__ app.c543a78e.js:1802fn 
app.c543a78e.js:2048(anonymous function) 
KeyConfigurer.ts?e3b4:8__webpack_modules__../KeyConfigurer.ts 
app.c543a78e.js:493__webpack_require__ app.c543a78e.js:1802fn 
app.c543a78e.js:2048(anonymous function) Main.tsx?e426:5__webpack_modules__../Main.tsx 
app.c543a78e.js:503__webpack_require__ app.c543a78e.js:1802(anonymous function) 
app.c543a78e.js:2958__webpack_require__.O app.c543a78e.js:1851(anonymous function) 
app.c543a78e.js:2959(anonymous function)
```

## Build Configuration

### webpack.config.json

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const SignageOSPlugin = require('@signageos/webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
const fs = require('fs');

var GitRevisionPlugin = require('git-revision-webpack-plugin');

var gitRevisionPlugin = new GitRevisionPlugin({
  commithashCommand: 'rev-list --max-count=1 --no-merges HEAD',
  versionCommand: 'rev-list HEAD --count',
  branchCommand: 'status --porcelain',
});

module.exports = {
  optimization: {
    minimize: false,
    // put all third-party libs into separate bundle file.
    // (https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/)
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        commons: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendors',
          chunks: 'all',
        },
      },
    },
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      __COMMITHASH__: JSON.stringify(gitRevisionPlugin.commithash()),
      __COMMITS_TOWARDS_HEAD__: JSON.stringify(gitRevisionPlugin.version()),
      __GIT_STATUS__: JSON.stringify(gitRevisionPlugin.branch()),
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: '../index_web.html',
    }),
    new Dotenv(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new SignageOSPlugin(),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
    }),
  ],
  entry: {
    app: ['core-js', 'whatwg-fetch', 'raf/polyfill', './Main.tsx'],
  },
  mode: 'development',
  devServer: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
  },
  devtool: 'eval-cheap-module-source-map',

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: new RegExp(fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('./non_ES5_node_modules'), 'utf-8').slice(1, -2)), // /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](?!(free-style|rtf.js|rtfjs)[\\/])/,
      },
      {
        /*
         * https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader/pull/116/commits/843c76eef19122142505ef3c4611ec5b2c70ba24#diff-04c6e90faac2675aa89e2176d2eec7d8
         * https://github.com/dbailo1988/html-loader#examples
         */
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'html-loader',
            options: {
              minimize: false,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /^(.(?!.module.css))*.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: ['/.jsx?$/', '/.js$/', '/.m?js$/'],
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
            plugins: [
              [
                // disabling strict mode for babel transform because free-style lib would fail
                '@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs',
                {
                  loose: true,
                  strictMode: false,
                },
              ],
            ],
          },
        },
        exclude: new RegExp(fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('./non_ES5_node_modules'), 'utf-8').slice(1, -2)), // /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](?!(free-style|rtf.js|rtfjs)[\\/])/,
      },
    ],
  },
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
    modules: ['src', 'node_modules'],
    fallback: { stream: require.resolve('stream-browserify') },
    alias: {
      process: 'process/browser', // shimming process/browser for chrome v37
      'free-style': 'free-style/dist.es5/index.js', // avoid es2015 build and use es5 dist files for free-style
    },
  },

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/'),
    filename: '[name].[hash:8].js',
    sourceMapFilename: '[name].[hash:8].map',
    chunkFilename: '[id].[hash:8].js',
  },
};
```

### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "./node_modules/gts/tsconfig-google.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "module": "ES6", //es6
    "target": "ES5",
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": false,
    "jsx": "react",
    "noEmit": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    // es2015.promise -> required for promises
    // es2017 -> required for maps/sets
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    // related to jest
    //"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    "typeRoots": ["../node_modules/@types"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    // "alwaysStrict": true,
    // disabling strict because free-style lib would fail
    "noImplicitUseStrict": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "src/**/*.spec.ts", "src/**/*.test.ts"],
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "test/**/*.ts", "typings/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*"]
}
```

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "newsrodeoviewer",
  "version": "2.0.3",
  "description": "NewsRodeo Viewer built with SignageOS middleware",
  "private": true,
  "main": "dist/index.html",
  "browserslist": [
    "since 2014",
    "dead",
    "chrome 37",
    "chrome 38"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
    "prepare": "npm run clean && npm run build",
    "upload": "sos applet upload",
    "clean": "gts clean",
    "escheck": "npx es-check --module=false es5 dist/*.js",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "postbuild": "npm run escheck",
    "connect": "webpack --watch",
    "lint": "gts lint",
    "test": "jest --watch",
    "test-failures": "jest --onlyFailures",
    "test-unit": "jest unit.test",
    "test-int": "jest int.tes",
    "dev-build": "npx webpack --mode development",
    "prod-build": "npx webpack --mode production",
    "compile": "tsc",
    "fix": "gts fix",
    "postinstall": "sh -c \"npx --silent are-you-es5 check -r . | tail -n 1 > ./non_ES5_node_modules \""
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.17.10",
    "@signageos/cli": "^1.0.2",
    "@signageos/webpack-plugin": "^0.3.0",
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.3",
    "@types/node": "^14.18.21",
    "@types/node-fetch": "^2.1.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.12",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.4",
    "amd-define-factory-patcher-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "are-you-es5": "^2.1.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^7.1.1",
    "git-revision-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.3",
    "gts": "^3.1.0",
    "html-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^28.1.1",
    "jest-css-modules": "^1.1.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^28.1.1",
    "node-fetch": "^2.2.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "ts-jest": "^28.0.5",
    "ts-loader": "^9.3.1",
    "tslint": "^5.11.0",
    "tslint-react": "^3.6.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "webpack": "^5.73.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.9.3",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@signageos/front-applet": "^5.3.0",
    "@signageos/front-display": "^9.16.2",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^3.1.43",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.4",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.24",
    "async-mutex": "^0.1.3",
    "circularbuffer": "^0.1.1",
    "core-js": "^3.23.3",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "free-style": "^3.2.4",
    "http-status-codes": "^1.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "raf": "^3.4.0",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-icons-kit": "^2.0.0",
    "react-live-clock": "^5.10.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-spinkit": "^3.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.9",
    "rtf.js": "^3.0.1",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "typesafe-actions": "^2.0.4",
    "typestyle": "^2.3.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^3.6.2",
    "xml-js": "^1.6.7"
  }
}
```

### non_ES5_node_modules

```
/[\\/]node_modules[\\/](?!(free-style|rtf.js)[\\/])/
```

I really need to solve this and have no clue what to do.
Please feel free to ask for additional information if necessary.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Look at the generated code. The error message tells you what line it is on. Knowing what is on the left hand side that is being assigned to is the first step to configuring everything to not generate that construct.